# Making this image using \smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-styles, smartdiagram

I at the moment trying to make this image.  I just found out there is a smart framework for making diagram named, `smartdiagram`. Is is possible to make this image, or something similar to this using `smartdiagram` ?

From the simple example i able to make a horizontal, but isn't how to add text on each arrow as in the image shown. 
[image]

Comment: Based on my knowledge of smartdiagram this would be exceed `smartdiagram`'s capabilities. I think, TikZ will do the trick.

Comment: Please always include the code you've got so far when asking a question in the form of a minimal but complete document we can compile. However, in this case, I wouldn't try to do this with `smartdiagram`. Even if it is possible, which it may not be, it will be a whole lot harder than just using Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With tikz

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzstyle{pinkbox}=[draw,rounded corners,shade,top color=white,bottom color=pink,
                     minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center,node distance=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{inter arrow}=[->,ultra thick,-{Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}]   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A)[pinkbox] {Signal Processing \&  \\ Feature Extraction};
\node (B)[pinkbox,below=of A] {Acoustic Model};
\node (C)[pinkbox,right=of B] {Language Model};
\node (D)[pinkbox,right=of A] {Hypothesis Search};

\draw[inter arrow] ($(A)+(0,2)$)--node[fill=white]{Audio Signal}(A);
\draw[inter arrow] (A)--node[fill=white]{Feature}(B);
\draw[inter arrow] (C)--node[fill=white]{LM Score}(D);
\draw[inter arrow] (D)--node[fill=white]{Recognition Result}($(D)+(0,2)$);
\draw[inter arrow] (B.east)--+(0.5,0)|-node[fill=white,pos=0.25]{AM Score}(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) By the way, I think it's generally recommended to use `\tikzset{stylename/.style={..}}` instead of `\tikzstyle{stylename}=[..]`.

Comment: I am having issues using `arrows.meta`... Any idea how to get it to work on ubuntu texmaker 4.5